# How to change movement of CCsprite dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am working on a game in which a sprite is jumping.. i want to change the movement of sprite dynamically. like when a jumping sprite reaches a particular position or cross the horizontal line then  the sprite should move in horizontal line.. 
any one knows? how to get this thing???

Comment: use CCMoveTo animation..

Comment: CCMoveTo are particularly bad for dynamic (ie frequently changing) movements due to 1-frame delay issues and doing a lot more work than a simple sprite.position = CGPointMake(whatever, whatever)

Comment: or even less to type `sprite.position = ccp( whatever, whatever );`.